# Factorise ideal into product of prime ideals?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am taking an undergraduate number theory course, and am trying to solve the following past paper question:
Let $p$ be a prime number, let $ζ$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity, and let $K = \mathbb{Q}(ζ)$. 
Factorise the ideal $(p)$ in $O_K$ into a product of prime ideals. 
The hint given is to consider the norm map and the element $1 - \zeta$. I think we have $N(1-\zeta)=\pm p$ but don't know how to use this. Any help appreciated!

Comment: The conjugates of $1-\zeta$ are $1-\zeta^k$. Now $1 - \zeta^2 = (1-\zeta)(1+\zeta)$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that $(p-1) O_K \subset \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$. Consider the map $s:O_k \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p$ given by addition of $p-1$ times the coordinates and reducing mod $p$. Clearly, $s(z)=(p-1)z=-z$ mod $1-\zeta$. Furthermore, as $p$ is the norm of $1-\zeta$, the kernel is exactly $(1-\zeta)$. It follows that $(1-\zeta)$ is a prime ideal.

Now check that $(1-\zeta)^{p-1} \in O_K^{\times}p$ (show that $\frac{1-\zeta^l}{1-\zeta^k}$ is always an algebraic integer), which concludes.

To prove the first claim: one inclusion is clear. To prove the other, we recall that if $u=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}{u_i\zeta^i}$ is an algebraic integer, then so us the sum of the conjugates of $\zeta^{p-k}u$, which is $(p-1)u_k$, thus the $u_k(p-1)$ are integers.